# How to add a delay when saving video frames as images

Tags: python, video-capture, opencv

I have a series of videos and I want to save frames from them as images. This is my code:

```
import os, cv2

current_dir = os.getcwd()
training_videos = '../../Videos/training_videos/'

if not os.path.exists(current_dir + '/training_images/'):
    os.mkdir(current_dir + '/training_images/')

for i in os.listdir(training_videos):

    video = cv2.VideoCapture('../../Videos/training_videos/' + i)

    currentFrame = 0

    while (True):
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = video.read()

        # Saves image of the current frame in jpg file
        name = current_dir + '/training_images/frame' + str(currentFrame) + '.png'
        print('Creating...' + name)
        cv2.imwrite(name, frame)

        # To stop duplicate images
        currentFrame += 1
```

This code works but unfortunately, it takes a frame at every millisecond. This is not something I want. Instead, I want to save a frame at every 5 or 10 seconds. I thought about adding a time delay but that wouldn't really work because the videos are not live streams so after 5 seconds, it'll just take the screenshot right after the previous millisecond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's likely an more efficient way, but you can do this by using the frame rate of the video and then processing the image every `FRAME_RATE * 5` frames.

Your code would look something like this (let me know if this doesn't work as I haven't ran this on my PC):

```
import os, cv2

current_dir = os.getcwd()
training_videos = '../../Videos/training_videos/'

if not os.path.exists(current_dir + '/training_images/'):
    os.mkdir(current_dir + '/training_images/')

for i in os.listdir(training_videos):

    video = cv2.VideoCapture('../../Videos/training_videos/' + i)
    fps = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

    currentFrame = 0

    while video.isOpened():
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = video.read()

        if (video):
            # Write current frame
            name = current_dir + '/training_images/frame' + str(currentFrame) + '.png'
            print('Creating...' + name)
            cv2.imwrite(name, frame)

            currentFrame += fps * 5
            # Skip to next 5 seconds
            video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, currentFrame)
```

Comment: This only creates the 1st image and nothing more. My guess is that it always overrides the first image.

Comment: @Axiumin_ You can move both frame counters at the top of the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `time.sleep(5)` try it:

```
import os, cv2
import time
framesToSkip = 120

current_dir = os.getcwd()
training_videos = '../../Videos/training_videos/'

if not os.path.exists(current_dir + '/training_images/'):
    os.mkdir(current_dir + '/training_images/')

for i in os.listdir(training_videos):

    video = cv2.VideoCapture('../../Videos/training_videos/' + i)

    currentFrame = 0

    while (True):
        # To stop duplicate images
        currentFrame += 1
        if currentFrame % framesToSkip != 0:
            continue
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = video.read()

        # Saves image of the current frame in jpg file
        name = current_dir + '/training_images/frame' + str(currentFrame) + '.png'
        print('Creating...' + name)
        cv2.imwrite(name, frame)
        time.sleep(5)
```

it will pause for 5 seconds and take save the next frame.

Comment: It seems like time does not have a pause function

Comment: sorry it was `sleep`

Comment: Yea sleep doesn't work. It is the same problem that I pointed out. Your approach would've worked if this was a live stream but it isn't. This is a local video and when you `sleep` for n seconds, it resumes from where it left of.

Comment: hum sorry you need to skeep some frames i will make a adjust on code

Comment: Same problem. Doesn't skip anything.

Comment: Also, sleep takes too long if I am going to create a dataset of thousands of images. There should be a way where I can divide this video into n frames..

Comment: i put 120 but you can change how many frames you wana skip before save another image

Comment: you can get the total frames from your video with `int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))`